# Post Apocalyptic world

Tags: post-apocalypse, climate-change

Im a Film student and I'm currently working on a idea for a film involving a world after global warming and the deconstruction of civilisation. Whilst my ideas won't all be realistic to the Nature of a possible post apocalyptic world. I want to get some things right. such as; a realistic year that those who 'survive' would begin to create small civilisations and groups again? What would realistically still be around and usable in terms of modern day technology and living? And what major changes would be in the new world?

ideally if you have any links to sources and even more information that would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We are a community dedicated to solve specific worldbuilding problem, while it seems you are asking us to develop your project for you. Sorry, we don't work that way. Visit the [help] and take the [tour] to understand our standard, and if possible rework your question to fit them.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if the answer to your question would take up an entire book (or in your case, an entire film), then it's too broad for this website. You should think about what specific parts of your post-apocalyptic world you would like help with creating, then take a look at the existing questions under the "post-apocalypse" tag to see whether they help you.

Comment: (1) What does "deconstruction of civilization" mean? (2) Why did civilization deconstruct? (Note that "global warming" is not really a realistic cause for loss of civilization. It may induce migrations, but what's bad for Texas is good for Siberia.) (3) How many people survive, and what is their technical and scientific level? (4) What do they intend to do by creating small civilisations? (5) What do you mean by *usable*? For example, our cities will be usable as sources of smelted metals for quite some time. (6) What is "modern day technology"? Hammers will be usable, smart phones not.

Comment: Have a look around for 'apocalypse', 'post apocalyptic' etc. there are quite a few questions and very nice answers here in Worldbuilding detailling the nitty gritty of decay and resurgence of civilisations.  Also please note that while Global Warming will kill huge numbers of people and change the face of the earth and earth's societies, it will not necessarily kill civilization. Not everywhere, at least. The warming is Global, the effects too, but the concrete outcomes (desertification, de-desertification, flooding, drying up,... ) are very much dependent on locale.

Comment: Interpersonal relationships and communities existed before the apocalypse, they'd exist one second after it.  *Nations* would take time, but how much requires knowing a thousand details about the apocalypse you haven't provided.  The same goes for what resources, etc., might be around.  At best, this is a series of individual questions (SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer), at worst you've asked us to write your script.  Per our [help/on-topic], we won't help you write your script (tell your story).  Can you [edit] your post to ask a single, specific question?